# making an android music app and keeping the activity alive

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing a music app for Android.
The problem is though that the App stops sometimes if i have open some other Apps and switch to them.

I would love to have it still running or even better have it in the Notification Bar like the Google Play Music App.

Can somebody hint me into the right direction? I have not found anything for my problem so far because I have one Activity running and most of the Solutions I found were for Services or just outdated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Service to keep your music play when the user is not using your app/or you app is killed. There are no other ways, you cannot say to android to keep your activity alive.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to understand more about services.

To let a service run foreaver (let it be a foreground service) you should create a notification and use [`startForeground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

A foreground service is a normal service with the difference it will be alive as long as the system can keep it alive. (with a notification which help to user to kill the service if not needed, in this case to stop the music player)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably Read The Official Documentation which happens to have a sample app of exactly that:

[Media Playback Training](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/index.html) and [Android Samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html)